# How to return RegExp.$ Parameters from a JSON of Parameters inside a Function() call?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string

I'm trying to return a set of parameters to RegExp.$ (a.k.a. f-strings of JS) from a JSON file.

```
const schema = require('../schema.json').Flights;
class flightRepo{
    keys = Object.keys(schema);

    create(db) {    
        return client.query(
            "INSERT INTO flights ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) VALUES ($7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12)",
            keys[0], keys[1], keys[2], keys[3], keys[4], keys[5],
            db.schema.keys[0], db.schema.keys[1], db.schema.keys[2], db.schema.keys[3], db.schema.keys[4], db.schema.keys[5]
        );
    }
}
```

*ABOUT*
client.query: Client Object from Deno's PostgreSQL Lib
db: passed list [args[0-5] for each key] to create new DB entry
create: function returns query status from PostgreSQL

*JSON STRUCTURE*

```
{
    "Flights" : {
        "FlightNo": "INT PRIMARY KEY",
        "Airlines": "STRING 50",
        "Time": "DATETIME",
        "OnTime": "BOOLEAN",
        "Dep": "STRING 4",
        "Arr": "STRING 4"
    }
}
```

What I wanted to do was remove the need of specifying n args manually (keys[0-5]) and ($1-12), and instead create an expression to do it for any x-item key list.

*(also it would be nice to know a way to remove the need to enter "Flights" JSON key in Ln.1)*

Comment: What is `client.query`? What is `db.schema`? Is `create`  method? There's no class or object around it, but no `function` keyword and it's not an arrow function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to make a few assumptions, but you can make the code vary the number of keys by creating the `$#` tokens based on the `keys` array (perhaps in a template literal) and using spread notation to spread out the `keys` and `db.schema.keys` arrays; see comments:

```
const schema = require('../schema.json').Flights;

class flightRepo {
//    ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− the convention is to capitalize this F
    keys = Object.keys(schema);

    create(db) {    
        return client.query(
            `INSERT INTO flights (${keys.map((_, i) => `${i + 1}`)}) VALUES (${keys.map((_, i) => `${i + 1 + keys.length}`)})`,
            ...keys,
            ...db.schema.keys // Assumes `db.schema.keys` is known to have the same length as `keys`
        );
    }
}
```

---

> also it would be nice to know a way to remove the need to enter "Flights" JSON key in Ln.1

You need to say what part of the object you want. You can relocate it if you want by using destructuring with renaming:

```
const {Flights: schema} = require('../schema.json');
```

...but what you have is probably clearer. Or of course, don't change the name:

```
const {Flights} = require('../schema.json');
```

...and use `Flights` instead of `schema`. But if it refers to something that isn't a constructor function, having it capitalized like that may be confusing.

Now that you've shown the JSON, we can see that (at least in this example) `Flights` is the only property of the object. If you can rely on that, you can do this:

```
const data = require("./schema.json");
const schema = data[Object.keys(data)[0]];
```